# Смена раскладки клавиатуры при заходе в мою программу

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Написал прогу на *Python Tkinter.* Что мне импортировать и как сделать так, чтобы **язык по умолчанию** менялся на Английский при заходе в неё? ( Язык печати, допустим я писал на русском, зашел в программу, а в ней сразу моя **раскладка переключилась на** Англ. )